# Use git to store system config

Tags: git

I want to use git to manage the config of my linux boxes. I started placing the repository folder into the system root:

```
cd /
git init
```

When I now move to the /etc folder and do a `git status` I get: "# Not currently on any branch." and see a list of all items in the root folder as "untracked files".

What am I doing wrong?

Oliver

Answer (score 4):

`git init` initializes an *empty* repository with no commits and no heads (i.e. branches). You have to add things first and create at least one commit to have a branch (`master`) created.

For example:

```
git add /etc/.
git commit -m 'Add all /etc/ data'
```

If you plan to use git for this, you should *really* add many files to a `.gitignore` though and generally only add those files explicitely you really want to add into the repository though.

Comment: That does not change anything on the initial problem, even after making a commit I get the same error as above.

Comment: Then your repository was not initialized correctly. Remove the `/.git/` folder and try it again, making sure you have the rights to write there.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use etckeeper which does store your etc config in a git (or any other dvcs) repository. It can be integrated with package managers to automatically create a new snapshot when you are installing packages.

http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/

Comment: etckeeper is also available as a package for Debian, Ubuntu, RHEL, CentOS, probably others.